# Why is it only executed once when generating dynamic javascript?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm making a web application based on `Express` and `axios`. I'm trying to create a static navigation and load an `HTML` file on each menu click while dynamically loading the associated script file.

### Page Router

```
... 
router.get('/page/home/:location', (req, res) => {
  const location = req.params.location;

  fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + `../../../views/pages/${location}.ejs`), (error, html) => {
    if(error) {
      res.status(500).end();
    } else {
      res.status(200).end(html);
    }
  });
});
```

### Main(.ejs)

```
...
<button class="nav-grid-item-menu-button" type="button" onclick="mainSidebarUiMouseclick(this)" value="diary">Diary</button>
...
<div id="content"></div>
```

### Controller

```
const mainSidebarUiMouseclick = (event) => {
  const content = document.getElementById('content');

  let script;

  // Remove all child
  content.innerHTML = '';

  axios.get(`${window.location.href}/${event.value}`)
    .then((res) => {
      content.innerHTML = res.data;
    })
    .then(() => {
      switch(event.value) {
        case 'diary':
          script = document.createElement('script');
         
          script.setAttribute('src', `/js/pages/ui-${event.value}-controller.mjs`);
          script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous'); 
          script.setAttribute('type', 'module'); 
          script.defer = true;

          script.addEventListener('load', () => { 
            console.info(`@system, Dynamic script loading complete`);
          });

          content.appendChild(script);
          break;
        ...
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.error(`@error, ${error}`); });
};
```

The script is always executed the first time it is clicked without any problem. However, if you return to another menu after moving to another menu, the script is not executed normally. This structure is not available for `document.body`. The reason is that all existing script files are dynamically erased when the menu is clicked. How should I solve it?

Comment: Which script or function is not executed the 2nd time you click a menu item?

Comment: Are you aware that `content.innerHTML = '';` is destroying the previous content that was in that element?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that's right. When you click the `Diary` menu for the first time, it works normally. However, if I click the `Diary` menu again after clicking another menu, the script is not executed. If you look in the `Chrome` inspector `DOM` tree, `<script>...</script>` does exist.

Comment: @jfriend00 I used it to remove all child elements to avoid linking to the same script.

Comment: Which script of function is not executed?

Comment: @jfriend00 `script.setAttribute('src', \`/js/pages/ui-${event.value}-controller.mjs\`);`. You can tell by looking at this code. The `init()` function inside that path is not executed.

Comment: Can you show us that script and show us what's in it?  Are you attempting to load the same script more than once?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's about `300` lines of code, so it's hard to understand. It's also a form of calling the same script file.

Comment: @jfriend00 No workaround? I've seen `eval()`, but I'm afraid to use it as it says it's a bad practice.

Comment: @jfriend00 I still don't quite understand what you're talking about. But roughly I understood how it works. Thanks :D.